# Passing props to the makeStyle in TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

How can I pass `post.mainImage` to `backgroundImage` style.

Here is my code;

```
import React from 'react';
import { Post } from '../interfaces';
import { makeStyles, createStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

type Props = {
  post: Post;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, Props>((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
      backgroundImage: ({ post }) => post.mainImage
    },
    date: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    heroimage: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
      height: 'auto',
      objectFit: 'cover'
    }
  })
);

export default function HeroPost({ post }: Props) {
  const classes = useStyles({ post });
  return (
    <Container className={classes.root}>
      <img alt={post.title} src={post.mainImage} className={classes.heroimage} />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

The code below has passed without a problem from the linter. But still cannot get the `backgroundImage` value on the front.

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (preferably on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can supply type variables to the call to `makeStyles` (note that the first one must be the theme type and the second the prop type):

```
type Props = {
  post: Post;
};

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, Props>(theme =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
      backgroundImage: ({ post }) => `url("${post.mainImage}")`
    },
    // ...
  })
);

export default function HeroPost({ post }: Props) {
  const classes = useStyles({ post });

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm aware this hack but as @Yatrix mentioned above, it's possible to pass with JS but couldn't find a solution for TypeScript.

Comment: Modified my answer - this should fix the TS issue.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I've used breakpoint to examine if `post` is defined on `backgroundImage: ({ post }) => post.mainImage`. Unfortunately it's= undefined.

Comment: Are you passing `post` or `{ post }` to `useStyles`?

Comment: `{ post }` as you used in the example.

Comment: The weird thing is that linter has correct item and everything seems ok. But still cannot get the value.

Comment: [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-morning-uodb5?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thnak you very much, `url("${post.mainImage}")` did the trick

Comment: Is there any good way of getting the default types for the return of `useStyles` as well? To make `className={classes.` autocomplete correctly?

Comment: Typescript seems to lose the inferred type when specifying the two first generic types. My way is to declare the styles as a separate const (`styles`) first and then setting the third generic for `makeStyles` to `keyof typeof styles`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: useStyles is a hook which can take a props in parameters and return the method useStyles.

```
const useStyles = (props: Props) => {
       const {post} = props;
    
       return makeStyles(theme => ({
           root: {
              maxWidth: '100%',
              backgroundImage: post.mainImage
           },
      }))
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass props with its type directly where you want to access it. This Should work fine.

```
type BgProps = {
  mainImage: string;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, Props>((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
      backgroundImage: (props: BgProps) => props.mainImage
    },
    date: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(2)
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You access the props like this,

`backgroundImage: props => props.backgroundImageProp`

https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#returns-3

Comment: This doesn't work. Must be related with TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Typescript :

```
   const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
           root: ({mainImage}: {mainImage: string}) => ({
                 ...
                 backgroundImage: mainImage
           })        
    })
        
    const component: React.FC => {
        const classes = useStyles({mainImage})
         return ...
    }
```